# SQL Query using count(*)

Tags: sql

I am wanting to list names and the number of times they have done a certain action.  I then want to order the names by the most amount of times.

I have the below code so far but I keep getting errors:

```
select name, count(*) as NoOfTimes
from CustName
group by count(*);
order by count(*) asc;
```

Comment: You have an extra semicolon before the `order by`.  This seems like a simple typographical error to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should note that if you want the *most* times at the beginning of the result set, the you want a descending sort:

```
select name, count(*) as NoOfTimes
from CustName
group by name
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to show count by name, you must group by name

```
select name, count(*) as NoOfTimes
from CustName
group by name
order by NoOfTimes desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by index also a good idea:

```
select name, count(*) as NoOfTimes
from CustName
group by name
order by 2 DESC
```